# Debugging Python with compiled extensions

Tags: python, debugging, fortran, cython, fortran-iso-c-binding

I use Python with compiled Cython and Fortran extensions (wrapped using modern Fortran's `iso_c_binding` module and Cython) for number crunching.

So far, I do not have a convenient debugging strategy. I use [`pudb`](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pudb) for the Python part. Although I might be able to use gdb on the Cython&Fortran parts of the project, I find myself to be using console text output (`print()!`) instead.

I'd like to know if there are tools that make the different levels of code transparent for debugging, i.e. I'm looking for a "one-tool-debugs-it-all" solution that doesn't care whether it steps Python, Cython or Fortran code.

I'd prefer tools that allow user-friendly interaction, such as the aforementioned pudb. Does such a jack of all trades debugging tool exist? Is the [Python mode of `GDB`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) the best I can get?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a solution for you, but I use GDB for exactly what you are describing. I looked around for a better solution too with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Cython debugger](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/debugging.html) which extends `gdb` with new commands that begin `cy`. These let you step through Cython code, set breakpoints, inspect locals etc. and still work just like the `py` commands from GDB's Python mode when you happen to be in a Python frame. There's no Fortran support unfortunately.

Comment: That's good advice for starting! Are there graphical frontends that work with `cygdb`? I couldn't find any. Also, I find it strange to run `cygdb` in the build directory.

Comment: You could try `ddd --pydb --debugger cygdb` or `ddd --gdb --debugger cygdb` to get `ddd` to run `cygdb` and pretend it's either `gdb` or `pydb`. Not sure how much functionality you'll get.

Comment: I am not familiar with `ddd`, but at least the very basics apparently work (as long as I do not stepping into system functions). I do get same visualization by clicking variables, so there is added value to the command line.

Apparently, as long as the Fortran routines used are compiled with debugging symbols, stepping into Fortran code is possible as well!

So now I only need to get familiar with `ddd`. Thank you!

Comment: Learning more about frontends to `gdb`, I came to the conclusion that `ddd` is my best shot at the time being. `gdb`s Python functionality is not exposed to the so called "machine interface". Thus, a Cython-aware graphical frontend needs to communicate with `gdb` over pty. Skimming through http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends, `ddd` is maybe the best I can get (now).

Answer (score 1):

You can try free PTVS + trial Intel Fortran + mixed mode debugging

see also

http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Mixed-mode%20debugging
http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/1974

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, I neither have access to Visual Studio nor to ifort.

Comment: You can get Visual Studio Express + PVTS for free

Comment: Not for Linux, I guess ;)

Comment: for Linux you can do remote debugging from PTVS!